# How to choose one .app project in xcode 4.5?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, uiapplicationdelegate

I have two example projects inside one project,In xcode products group BumpSphereExample.app,TeapotExample.app two files and two firstdelegate,seconddelegate delegate classes.

I changed settings in target,but its not working.
Default TeapotExample project running,i need to run BumpSphereExample.
how to choose one project in Xcode?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHFYW.png]

Comment: They have to be in separate projects.  So remove all the files related to the project you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

I found answer myself . Just by changing the destination option near the run button as in the image we can run the single project

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHWL1.png